# In neural network compression, what's the meaning of 'reducing redundancies in the model parameters'

Tags: parameters, neural-network, compression

In the `Introduction` of paper [Combined Group and Exclusive Sparsity for Deep Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/yoon17a/yoon17a.pdf), it says

> One way to obtain a compact deep network is by
>   reducing redundancies in the model parameters. In the optimal
>   case, the weights at each layer will be fully orthogonal
>   to each other, and thus forming an orthogonal basis
>   set.

I just wonder what is the meaning of `the weights are orthogonal`, and why it can reduce redundancies in the model parameters, resulting in a compact deep network.